# Change the mssqlserver decimal separator with comma

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am doing application for french based company, I need to store decimal value like(12,2) in MS sqlserever.I need to use comma(,) instead of (.) in decimal field.

Comment: It is not stored as text. It is stored as numbers. You want to read it, and convert the decimal value to a string with commas. The `FORMAT` function would be great, but unfortunately it needs 2012+. See the answers to the duplicate question for a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Insert an encoder/decoder in your injection screening layer.

Alternatively, store your data as character sequence.